# Open a custom webpart from the other custom webpart through a link button

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

How to Open a custom webpart from the other custom webpart through a link buttom.

I have a custom webpart in which i have a link buttons of all other custom webparts in that page.On click event the particular webpart should be open.

can anyone please help me in solving this...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Open a custom webpart" ?

If you want to make some operations on webparts, you can use the [splimitedwebpartmanager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you need to follw this step to open the custom web part on page:

(1) create seperate page for each custom web part.
(2) add web part on the page.
(3) set url to related web part page.

hope this help.